# Laravel 5.7 auth behavior

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

I'm new to Laravel and have been tracing it's code several days now to understand its behavior but to no avail.

Suppose I add middleware to a route like this

```
Route::group(["middleware" => ["web", "auth:web", "auth:custom"]], function() {
    Route::view("/about", "about");
});
```

1. Does the `/about` route go through `auth:web` followed by `auth:custom`?
   If not, what is the behavior?
2. How do I create a `auth:custom` guard that does not conflict with `auth:web`? The current behavior is that, if `auth:web` is authenticated, `auth:custom` follows it's status, I suspect they are sharing the same session variable.

I'm really new to Laravel and this appears to be a mix of route, auth and middleware. Hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - Your route will use middlewares from `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider`. See:

```
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace)
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Every middleware you write will be executed in the order you define. If one middleware fails, `$next($request);` won't be called. So the next middleware won't get activated.

2- These `auth:web` and `auth:custom` middlewares are the 'auth middleware' calls, but with different parameters. Everything after `:` are being sent to handle method of the middleware as parameters.

The auth middleware is defined under `App\Http\Kernel` class under `$routeMiddleware` var:

```
'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
```

and here is the `handle` method:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string[]  ...$guards
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
{
    $this->authenticate($guards);

    return $next($request);
}
```

Your 'web' or 'custom' parameter goes to ...$guards parameter.

By the way, there is no predefined 'custom' guard. You have to write your own custom guard and define it under `config/auth.php`, `guards` array:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [ // This is the web guard (auth:web)
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [ // and this the api guard (auth:api)
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

Then you can expect laravel auth middleware to authenticate using your custom guard like `auth:custom` or `auth:acme`.